# Откуда берутся нули? и как их убрать

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть запрос к базе данных на вычисление процентов:

```
SELECT 
  group, 
  count, 
  ROUND(count*100.0/ (SELECT sum(count) from table) ,2) as [%] 
FROM table
```

`count` типа `int`

В результате выводятся числа округленные до двух знаков после запятой, но с кучей нулей после 2 цифр. Можно ли как то убрать эти нули?

Comment: это где  у вас выводится  к кучей нулей? пока что видно что у вас поля в `select` и `group by` различаются, и запрос не рабочий. Если нули у вас выводяся в каком то приложении, то это не проблема запроса. да и подзапрос тут не нужен, скорее всего

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам надо привести результат к типу с 2 знаками после запятой, например - `numeric(18,2)`, где вторая цифра как раз определяет количество знаков после запятой.
Итоговый запрос будет выглядеть вот так:

```
  SELECT 
  group, 
  count, 
  CAST(count*100.0/ (SELECT sum(count) from table) as numeric(18,2)) as [%]
FROM table
```

Comment: спасибо за комментарий, в процессе правок часть кода потерлась - сейчас исправлю

Comment: @Akina исправил ;)

Comment: Ну вот, другое дело! Хотя мануал https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql выполняет приведение типа не для результата ROUND(), а для его аргумента (см. Remarks). И именно так - правильно.

Comment: убрал round, т.к. при cast с усечением дробной части округление производится автоматически